# Checking that $\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2]}{\langle x_1^2\rangle}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, finitely-generated, algebras

From NPTEL's Commutative Algebra online course, lecture 17  ([link here in the time of the video the example is given](https://youtu.be/Zp1ttfuEfrk?t=2033)), it is given the following example concerning a non-finite $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra:

> **Example:** $B=\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2]}{\langle x_1^2\rangle}$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra and a generating set for $B$ is
>   $$
> G=\{\overline{x}_1^j \overline{x}_2^i: 0\leq j \leq 1,\, 0\leq i \leq \infty\}
> $$
>   Note that $B$ is not a finite $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra.

---

From the definition of a finitely generated $A$-algebra (Atiyah - MacDonald pg 30):

> The homomorphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ is of finite type and $B$ is a finitely generated $A$-algebra if there exists a finite set of elements $x_1,...,x_n$ in $B$ such that every element of $B$ can be written as a polynomial in $x_1,...,x_n$ with coefficients in $f(A)$.

Here obviously $A=\mathbb{Z}$. It's not clear to me why $B$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra. The homomorphism $f$ is not given explicitely so I assumed it's $n\mapsto n\cdot 1$, so that $f(\mathbb{Z})=f(A)=\{ \overline{n} \in B: n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

I can't see why any element in $B$ is written as a polynomial (coefficients in $f(\mathbb{Z})$ of finite elements of $B$. It seems to me that given any finite set of $B$ i can find an element of $B$ outside its span. Maybe I got the definition wrong. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Isn't $B=\mathbb Z[x_1,\overline{x_2}]$, where $\overline{x_2}$ is the residue class of $x_2$ modulo the ideal generated by its square?

Comment: The quotient is over the ideal generated by $x_1^2$, not $x_2^2$.

Comment: Ok. Then switch between 1 and 2 in my comment.

Comment: Furthermore, pointing out an infinite system of generators for a module (or a vector space) does not make it infinitely generated on the spot. One has to prove that there is no finite system of generators! (Maybe he was aware of this, but the audience was so passive that let it at it was and moved farther.)

Comment: The audience indeed was kinda passive at the time.